# JQuery Load Local Storage Disables Dialog Opening on click

Tags: jquery, local-storage, jquery-ui-dialog

There is a lot of code to look at so I put it in a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/mikegriffinn/S7pvz/.

It is an html table as an editable stoplight scorecard with local storage using JQuery.

The scorecard edit buttons work fine until I load the saved table from local storage.

When I load the local storage, the edit buttons no longer open the dialog widget with the edit form. When I clear the local storage, they work again. There are no errors in the console. Any ideas why?

Since there are a ton of lines to the table and update form code in the html, I'll just put the JavaScript here. You can look at the full code in the fiddle.

Here's the JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
     autoOpen: false,     
     buttons: {
         Update: function() {
              // Set the variables equal to the values in the form input fields
              // eg <input type = "text" id="test1">
            var r1 = $( "#r1").val(),
                g1 = $( "#g1").val(),
                p1 = $( "#p1" ).val(),
                p2 = $( "#p2" ).val(),
                p3 = $( "#p3" ).val(),
                p4 = $( "#p4" ).val(),
                p5 = $( "#p5" ).val(),
                p6 = $( "#p6" ).val(),
                row = $( this ).data( "editingRow" );

            //find the cells matching the form input fields and insert the value in the fields
            row.find("td").eq(1).text( r1 );
            row.find("td").eq(2).text( g1 );
            row.find("td").eq(3).text( p1 );
            row.find("td").eq(4).text( p2 );
            row.find("td").eq(5).text( p3 );
            row.find("td").eq(6).text( p4 );
            row.find("td").eq(7).text( p5 );
            row.find("td").eq(8).text( p6 );
            colorUp();
            $( this ).dialog("close");
         },
     Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
     }
});
//create the click handler for the edit button
$( ".abtn" ).on( "click", function() {
  //set the value of the row variable
    var row = $( this ).closest("tr");
//find the values in each of the cells in that row
    var rName = row.find( "td" ).eq( 0 ).text(),
        r1 = row.find( "td" ).eq( 1 ).text(),
        g1 = row.find( "td" ).eq( 2 ).text(),
        p1 = row.find( "td" ).eq( 3 ).text(),
        p2 = row.find( "td" ).eq( 4 ).text(),
        p3 = row.find( "td" ).eq( 5 ).text(),
        p4 = row.find( "td" ).eq( 6 ).text(),
        p5 = row.find( "td" ).eq( 7 ).text(),
        p6 = row.find( "td" ).eq( 8 ).text();
//set the value of the input boxes to the current value in the cells
    $( "#r1" ).val( r1 );
    $( "#g1" ).val( g1 );
    $( "#p1" ).val( p1 );
    $( "#p2" ).val( p2 );
    $( "#p3" ).val( p3 );
    $( "#p4" ).val( p4 );
    $( "#p5" ).val( p5 );
    $( "#p6" ).val( p6 );

//change the title of the dialog box to Editing Row Name
// use the data(key, value) method to store a reference to the <tr>
// open the dialog box
    $( "#dialog" )
        .dialog( "option", {
            title: "Editing " + rName
            })
        .data( "editingRow", row )
        .dialog( "open" );
});


    function colorUp() {
       $('#heat-map-3 > tbody > tr').each(function (i, row) {
          for (var i = 3; i < 9; i++) {
             var $row = $(row),
                $r1 = parseInt($row.find( "td" ).eq( 1 ).text()),
                $g1 = parseInt($row.find( "td" ).eq( 2 ).text()),
                $pVal = parseInt($row.find( "td" ).eq( i ).text()),

                red = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
                yellow = 'rgb(255,204,0)';
                green = 'rgb(0,255,0)';
                var clr;

                if ($r1 < $g1) {
                    if  ( $pVal < $r1 ) {
                      clr = red;
                    }
                    else if  ($r1 === $pVal || $pVal < $g1) {
                       clr = yellow;
                    }
                    else {
                      clr = green;
                    }
                 }
                 else  {
                    if  ( $pVal > $r1 ) {
                      clr = red;
                    }
                    else if  ($r1 === $pVal || $pVal < $g1) {
                       clr = yellow;
                    }
                    else {
                      clr = green;
                    }
                 }



                $row.find( "td" ).eq( i ).css({backgroundColor:clr});
             }
       })
    }
    colorUp();

    $( "#saveSc" ).click(function(){
       var scorecard = $('#scorecard').html();
       localStorage.setItem('scorecard', scorecard);
       return false;
    });


   $( " #loadSc ").click(function() {
        if(localStorage.getItem('scorecard')) {
            $('#scorecard').html(localStorage.getItem('scorecard'));
        }
    });

    $('#clearSc').click( function() {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    location.reload();
    return false;
    });

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your fiddle with the correction: http://jsfiddle.net/S7pvz/14/

The problem comes from your js structure: in your `$(document).ready` your were creating the edit button for the click behaviour:

```
$(".abtn").on("click", function() { ... }
```

But, when you load the items from the localstorage, you are doing the following:

```
$('#scorecard').html(localStorage.getItem('scorecard'));
```

Or all your edit buttons are included in the scorecard div you are overwritting, so the click behaviour is dropped.

To change it, I included the click management inside a function, called inside your document.ready, and also after your localStorage loading: see `activateEditButtons()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,     
        buttons: {
            Update: function() {
                // Set the variables equal to the values in the form input fields
                // eg <input type = "text" id="test1">
                var r1 = $("#r1").val(),
                    g1 = $("#g1").val(),
                    p1 = $("#p1").val(),
                    p2 = $("#p2").val(),
                    p3 = $("#p3").val(),
                    p4 = $("#p4").val(),
                    p5 = $("#p5").val(),
                    p6 = $("#p6").val(),
                    row = $(this).data("editingRow");

                //find the cells matching the form input fields and insert the value in the fields
                row.find("td").eq(1).text(r1);
                row.find("td").eq(2).text(g1);
                row.find("td").eq(3).text(p1);
                row.find("td").eq(4).text(p2);
                row.find("td").eq(5).text(p3);
                row.find("td").eq(6).text(p4);
                row.find("td").eq(7).text(p5);
                row.find("td").eq(8).text(p6);
                colorUp();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    function activateEditButtons() {
        //create the click handler for the edit button
        $(".abtn").on("click", function() {
            //set the value of the row variable
            console.log(this);
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");

            //find the values in each of the cells in that row
            console.log("before find val");
            var rName = row.find("td").eq(0).text(),
                r1 = row.find("td").eq(1).text(),
                g1 = row.find("td").eq(2).text(),
                p1 = row.find("td").eq(3).text(),
                p2 = row.find("td").eq(4).text(),
                p3 = row.find("td").eq(5).text(),
                p4 = row.find("td").eq(6).text(),
                p5 = row.find("td").eq(7).text(),
                p6 = row.find("td").eq(8).text();

            console.log("before set val");
            //set the value of the input boxes to the current value in the cells
            $("#r1").val(r1);
            $("#g1").val(g1);
            $("#p1").val(p1);
            $("#p2").val(p2);
            $("#p3").val(p3);
            $("#p4").val(p4);
            $("#p5").val(p5);
            $("#p6").val(p6);

            //change the title of the dialog box to Editing Row Name
            // use the data(key, value) method to store a reference to the <tr>
            // open the dialog box
            console.log("before dialog opening");
            $("#dialog")
                .dialog("option", {
                    title: "Editing " + rName
                })
                .data("editingRow", row)
                .dialog("open");
        });
    }

    function colorUp() {
        $('#heat-map-3 > tbody > tr').each(function (i, row) {
            for (var i = 3; i < 9; i++) {
                var $row = $(row),
                    $r1 = parseInt($row.find("td").eq(1).text()),
                    $g1 = parseInt($row.find("td").eq(2).text()),
                    $pVal = parseInt($row.find("td").eq(i).text()),
                    red = 'rgb(255,0,0)';

                yellow = 'rgb(255,204,0)';
                green = 'rgb(0,255,0)';
                var clr;

                if ($r1 < $g1) {
                    if ($pVal < $r1) {
                        clr = red;
                    } else if ($r1 === $pVal || $pVal < $g1) {
                        clr = yellow;
                    } else {
                        clr = green;
                    }
                }
                else  {
                    if ($pVal > $r1) {
                        clr = red;
                    } else if ($r1 === $pVal || $pVal < $g1) {
                        clr = yellow;
                    } else {
                        clr = green;
                    }
                }
                $row.find("td").eq(i).css({backgroundColor:clr});
            }
        });
    }

    activateEditButtons();
    colorUp();

    $("#saveSc").click(function() {
        var scorecard = $('#scorecard').html();
        localStorage.setItem('scorecard', scorecard);
        return false;
    });

    $("#loadSc").click(function() {
        if(localStorage.getItem('scorecard')) {
            $('#scorecard').html(localStorage.getItem('scorecard'));
            activateEditButtons();
        }
    });

    $('#clearSc').click(function() {
        window.localStorage.clear();
        location.reload();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll thoroughly noodle the solution to see if I can grok it well enough not to make the same mistake in the future!!!

Comment: You're welcome. If you validate the correction, don't forget to accept the answer, thanks